# Hashcat:: Token length exception. No hashes loaded

Tags: hashcat

I'm trying to crack a wallet.dat hash from an old file from 2013. I created a hash with `bitcoin2john` and it is 112 characters. I can't get it to work.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong with my command or the hash itself. I've seen on other sites the Bitcoin Core wallet.dat dashes are sometimes 114 or 115 characters.

I used the blockchain explorer site to check the wallet and verify it has coins.

Any suggestions?

I had the hash in a text file. I've tried pasting it into the command line with single quotes but now I'm getting a token length exception error. Hash has been redacted. The actual hash is 112 characters and gives the same error with this code.

```
hashcat -a 3 -m 11300 'full 112 character hash goes here' --force

hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...

OpenCL Platform #1: Intel(R) Corporation
========================================
* Device #1: Intel(R) Gen12LP HD Graphics NEO, 4095/25477 MB allocatable, 96MCU

OpenCL Platform #2: Intel(R) Corporation
========================================
* Device #2: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz, skipped.

Hash: '$bitcoin$64$2...' Token length exception No hashes loaded.
```

Comment: I was unable to find if there's a standardized length for these hashes. Maybe someone here knows?

Comment: Does the hash look like the example here: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes

Comment: It does except it's only 112 characters and that example is 302. I have seen other examples that were only 114 or 115 though and those worked, so I don't know if the length is standardized. It would appear not. I'm thinking maybe I need to try another program to extract the hash?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the wallet hash range, but the current version of the question now meets our criteria. Hopefully someone else might know.